# Can Q.js be used without node.js and require?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, requirejs, q

I am trying to use the latest q.js to add promises to my ajax calls. I don't use node.js in any way shape or form. I downloaded the latest from https://github.com/kriskowal/q and include just the q.js. In my console I see in some places:

ReferenceError: require is not defined

I don't know if this is a deal breaker or not, but I don't use requirejs either. I am playing around with a single page app, and while I use jquery for ajax, I plan to remove that dependency for either my own simple implementation or another smaller library. I want to use q.js, and also use bootstrap.js and will possibly use flatiron-director, that's about it. So I don't use npm, or any of that other stuff since my app is so simple. With only a couple JS files, I don't see any reason to add that complexity.

So is that error a problem and q.js won't work without require.js (or node.js)? I thought I read it's stand alone, but when I see errors like this and it seems as if it depends on some other JS libraries it has me doubting if I can use it or not.

Comment: If you look at the "Getting started" section in the readme, you can see *"The Q module can be loaded as: [...] A `<script>` tag (creating a Q global variable): ~2.5 KB minified and gzipped."*

Comment: Yes..I did see that, and did that, but even doing that I am seeing it is trying to use require() to load some other scripts. If that is ok..I am fine with it. I just saw the console error and thought perhaps I am doing something wrong with trying to use it.

Comment: @user3317868 It should definitely work. Are you loading anything else onto the page that might be confusing it? You should do some debugging to make a reduced test case.

Comment: I do load jquery 2.1, bootstrap js, and directorjs. But the error is definitely from the q.js loading..or trying to use the require() call that is not present because I did not load requirejs or nodejs. I haven't used the promise stuff yet, but I'll see if it works despite this console log error. I assume it's attempting to use require() *just in case* it was loaded by nodejs maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The V2 branch of this project uses require.js.  The V1 branch does not use require.js.
https://github.com/kriskowal/q/tree/v1